# What is it called when an informational clause is added in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is the name of this sentence format called, when a clause of information is embedded in the middle of a sentence?  I have highlighted the clauses of concern in bold.

> I first met George, **my sister's husband**, when he was staying, **to my dismay**, at our, **my parent's**, downtown home.

If this were spoken, then probably the bold text above would be said in a lower or softer voice.

In all of these cases, the clause can be removed and the sentence is still intact.

> I first met George when he was staying at our downtown home.

Note, I'm not debating if using this sentence structure is good or valid syntax.  I'm just wondering if there's a name for having a written or spoken clause within a sentence.  Is it simply just called a *clause*, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [**parenthetical clauses**](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-parenthetic-clause-230141).

They can be omitted without changing the syntax of the sentence, and they are usually set off by commas, dashes, or some other punctuation.  (Note that parentheses are occasionally used to set off such clauses, but commas are far more common.)